# Serialize and skip if doesn't exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, gamesparks

I am using Unity with GameSparks and have a serializer script which makes a GameSparks data object into a c# model. The script looks like this:

```
public static object GSDataToObject(GSData gsData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("GSSerializer Return: \n"+gsData.JSON);

        Type objType = Type.GetType(gsData.GetString("type"));

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

        foreach(var typeField in objType.GetFields())
        {
            if(!typeField.IsNotSerialized)
            {
                if(typeField.FieldType == typeof(string))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, gsData.GetString(typeField.Name));
                }
                else if(typeField.FieldType == typeof(int))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, (int)gsData.GetNumber(typeField.Name).Value);    
                }
                else if(typeField.FieldType == typeof(float))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, (float)gsData.GetFloat(typeField.Name).Value);    
                }
                else if(typeField.FieldType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, gsData.GetBoolean(typeField.Name));    
                }
                else if(typeField.FieldType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, gsData.GetDate(typeField.Name));    
                }
                else if((typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<string>) || typeField.FieldType == typeof(string[]) ))
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, (typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<string>)) ? (object)gsData.GetStringList(typeField.Name) : gsData.GetStringList(typeField.Name).ToArray());  
                }
                else if((typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<int>) || typeField.FieldType == typeof(int[])) )
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, (typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<int>)) ? (object)gsData.GetIntList(typeField.Name) : gsData.GetIntList(typeField.Name).ToArray());    
                }
                else if((typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<float>) || typeField.FieldType == typeof(float[])) )
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, (typeField.FieldType == typeof(List<float>)) ? (object)gsData.GetFloatList(typeField.Name) : gsData.GetFloatList(typeField.Name).ToArray());    
                }

                else if(typeField.FieldType.IsClass && !typeField.FieldType.IsGenericType && !typeField.FieldType.IsArray)
                {
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, GSDataToObject(gsData.GetGSData(typeField.Name)));
                }
                else if(!typeField.FieldType.IsArray && typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(typeField.FieldType))
                {
                    IList genericList = Activator.CreateInstance(typeField.FieldType) as IList;
                    foreach(GSData gsDataElem in gsData.GetGSDataList(typeField.Name))
                    {
                        object elem = GSDataToObject(gsDataElem);
                        genericList.Add(elem);
                    }
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, genericList);
                }
                else if(typeField.FieldType.IsArray)
                {
                    List<GSData> gsArrayData = gsData.GetGSDataList(typeField.Name);
                    // create a new instance of the array. The Activator class cannot do this for arrays //
                    // so this will create a new array of types inside the array, with the count of what is in the gsdata list //
                    Array newArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeField.FieldType.GetElementType(), gsArrayData.Count);
                    object[] objArray = new object[gsArrayData.Count]; // create a new array of objects where the serialized objects will be kept
                    for(int i = 0; i < gsArrayData.Count; i++)
                    {
                        objArray[i] = GSDataToObject(gsArrayData[i]); // convert the JSON data inside the list to an object
                    }
                    Array.Copy(objArray, newArray, objArray.Length); //covert the object[] to the original type
                    typeField.SetValue(obj, newArray);
                }

            }
        }

        return obj;
}
```

My model like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UserData
{
    public string name;
    public string email;
}
```

I then call the script when I get data from GameSparks like this:

```
UserData uData = new UserData();
uData = GameSparksSerialiser.GSDataToObject(response.ScriptData.GetGSData("@userReturn")) as UserData;
```

Now, all this works perfect, but if i decide to add a new field in all new created documents (mongodb) from now on, I have an issue. I add the new field to my model in Unity like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
 public class UserData
 {
     public string name;
     public string email;
     public bool isAdmin;
 }
```

This makes no errors for all the new documents, but when trying to serialize an old document, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

Now, how can i avoid this, using the serializer script... Is it possible to not make the error, so I don't have to change all the old documents?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Please post the complete error message you get including stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what `GSData` is or how the getters are implemented but the issue seems to come from e.g. (would have helped if you included the full error message)

```
typeField.SetValue(obj, gsData.GetBoolean(typeField.Name));
```

where you are trying to get a value for a field that didn't exist before.

You should wrap it in a `try-catch` block. In order to not have to do it for each and every case you should probably wrap the entire

```
foreach(var typeField in objType.GetFields())
{
    try{        
        if(!typeField.IsNotSerialized)
        {
            .......
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"{e.GetType} while trying to get value for {typeField.Name}: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

This will still throw an error in the console but not like an exception usually would break your app / for loop but rather simply continue with the rest.

---

General sidenote:

It is quite redundant to do

```
UserData uData = new UserData();
```

right before using

```
uData = GameSparksSerialiser.GSDataToObject(response.ScriptData.GetGSData("@userReturn")) as UserData;
```

This creates only some work for the GarbageCollector for destroying this not used instance of `UserData` create by `new`. Simply directly use

```
UserData uData = GameSparksSerialiser.GSDataToObject(response.ScriptData.GetGSData("@userReturn")) as UserData;
```